# Starting with Spirit X3

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

I've just started using Spirit X3 and I have a little question related with my first test. Do you know why this function is returning "false"?

```
bool parse()
{
    std::string rc = "a 6 literal 8";

    auto iter_begin = rc.begin();
    auto iter_end = rc.end();

    bool bOK= phrase_parse( iter_begin, iter_end,
                            // ----- start parser -----

                            alpha >> *alnum >> "literal" >> *alnum

                            // ----- end parser -----
                            , space);

    return bOK && iter_begin == iter_end;
}
```

I've seen the problem is related with how I write the grammar. If I replace it with this one, it returns "true"

```
alpha >> -alnum >> "literal" >> *alnum
```

I'm using the Spirit version included in Boost 1.61.0.

Thanks in advance,

Sen

Comment: Here you can test the code online: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ce333c6e9f75f66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a combination of the greediness of operator `*` and the use of a skipper. You need to keep in mind that `alnum` is a `PrimitiveParser` and that means that before every time this parser is tried, Spirit will pre-skip, and so the behaviour of your parser is:

- `alpha` parses `a`.
- The kleene operator starts.
- `alnum` skips the space and then parses `6`.
- `alnum` skips the space and then parses `l`.
- `alnum` parses `i`.
- ...
- `alnum` parses `l`.
- `alnum` skips the space and then parses `8`.
- `alnum` tries and fails to parse more. This completes the kleene operator with a parsed attribute of `6literal8`.
- `"literal"` tries and fails to parse.
- The sequence operator fails and the invocation of `phrase_parse` returns `false`.

You can easily avoid this problem using the `lexeme` directive ([barebones x3 docs](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/quick_reference/directive.html), [qi docs](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/lexeme.html)). Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1913efa728929b2b) should work:

```
alpha >> lexeme[*alnum] >> "literal" >> lexeme[*alnum];
```